# ¿Cómo obtener token de sharepoint con usuario y contraseña hardcode?

Tags: xamarin.forms, sharepoint-online

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación que descarga información de sharepoint. Hasta ahora puedo descargar la información, pero para ello al abrir la app tengo que hacer login en Microsoft. Necesito encontrar una forma de hacer login mandando el usuario y contraseña harcode, para que el usuario que utilice la app no tenga la necesidad de hacerlo.

Con esta línea puedo realizar solicitudes nuevas, pero como ven mando un token obtenido con el login:

```
this.client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", this.token);
```

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar el código donde obtienes ese token?

Comment: Claro. esta es la interface> public interface IAuthenticator
    {
        Task<AuthenticationResult> Authenticate(string authority, string resource, string clientId, string returnUri);
    }

Comment: public class Authenticator : IAuthenticator{ public async Task<AuthenticationResult> Authenticate(string authority, string resource, string clientId, string returnUri) {var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);       if (authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().Any())
                authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().First().Authority);
            var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientId, new Uri(returnUri), new PlatformParameters((Activity)Forms.Context));
            return authResult;
        }
    }

Comment: parece que estas usando sharepoint online, para poder iniciar sesion necesitas el pnp authentication Manager aqui hay una guia de como usar el PnP authentication manager con Credenciales en el codigo. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/authenticate-sharepoint-using-pnp-authentication-manager/